# mysql right join as discussed in the example is not giving right result

Tags: mysql

i have a table A with a as a column and table B  as a , name, address

table A has 1,1,2 as input 
table B has (1, hello , india), (1,hi, nowhere),( 2,hukka,china) as values

```
SELECT * FROM a 
right join b 
on a.a=b.a 
and b.a=1 
and a.a is not null
```

its giving me

```
  a     a   name    address
  1     1   hello   india
  1     1   hi  nowhere
NULL    2   hukka   china
```

any clues why its still showing me null value for a.a

Comment: Spend some more time presenting your question -- 'table A has 1,1,2 as input' isn't helpful.

Comment: why you didnt use where clause?

Comment: A search for 'right join' on SO currently returns approximately 2000 results. By contrast a search for 'left join' returns approximately 48000. Does this tell you anything? If not, I think it should!

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use a `WHERE` clause

```
SELECT * FROM a 
RIGHT JOIN b 
ON a.a=b.a 
WHERE b.a=1 
AND a.a IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT a.a, b.a, b.name, b.address 
FROM a 
INNER JOIN b ON a.a = b.a 
WHERE b.a = 1 AND a.a IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: i m just thinking why my query dont give me the desired result. i mean whatz wrong with my query when u use 2 conditions after on.